# Is there a function to return all of rows and exclude the rows that doesn't match the condition in python dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I want to exclude the rows whose 'Total' column is '-', and only return every rows that has a value on the 'Total' column. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

input_csv_file = "./CSV/Officers_and_Shareholders.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(input_csv_file, skiprows=10, on_bad_lines='skip')
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
df.columns = ['Nama', 'Jabatan', 'Alamat', 'Klasifikasi Saham', 'Jumlah Lembar Saham', 'Total']

df['Total'] = df.index if df.index.tolist() else range(len(df))

idx = df.index.get_loc(df['Total'].eq('-').idxmin())
officer = df.loc[:idx]
shareholder = df.loc[idx:]

for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    if df["Total"][i] == '-':
        shareholders = shareholder
        print(i, shareholders)
    else:
        officers = officer
        print(i, officers)
```

I tried applying the following code:

```
df['Total'] = df.index if df.index.tolist() else range(len(df))
```

The code on the above returns the same row, which is row 0 with the following content:

```
0             Nama   Jabatan Alamat Klasifikasi Saham Jumlah Lembar Saham  Total
0  ALIF SASETYO,  DIREKTUR  Jalan                 -                   -      0
1             Nama   Jabatan Alamat Klasifikasi Saham Jumlah Lembar Saham  Total
0  ALIF SASETYO,  DIREKTUR  Jalan                 -                   -      0
2             Nama   Jabatan Alamat Klasifikasi Saham Jumlah Lembar Saham  Total
0  ALIF SASETYO,  DIREKTUR  Jalan                 -                   -      0
3             Nama   Jabatan Alamat Klasifikasi Saham Jumlah Lembar Saham  Total
0  ALIF SASETYO,  DIREKTUR  Jalan                 -                   -      0
4             Nama   Jabatan Alamat Klasifikasi Saham Jumlah Lembar Saham  Total
0  ALIF SASETYO,  DIREKTUR  Jalan                 -                   -      0
```

Is there anyway to return all of the rows for those 'Total' column is either 0 or '-'? If the code is able to return every rows, it should return the following:

```
                                                 Nama  ...              Total
0                                       ALIF SASETYO,  ...                  -
1                               NIK: 3171060201830005  ...                   
2                               NPWP: 246383541071000  ...                   
3                       TTL: Jakarta, 02 Januari 1983  ...                   
4                                     ARIEF HERMAWAN,  ...                  -
5                               NIK: 1271121011700003  ...                   
6                               NPWP: 070970173112000  ...                   
7                        TTL: Bogor, 10 November 1970  ...                   
8                                 ARLAN SEPTIA ANANDA  ...                   
9                                              RASAM,  ...                   
10                              NIK: 3174051209620003  ...                   
11                              NPWP: 080878200013000  ...                   
12                         TTL: Jakarta, 12 September  ...                   
13                                               1962  ...                   
14                                   CHAIRAL TANJUNG,  ...                  -
15                              NIK: 3171011605660004  ...                   
16                              NPWP: 070141650093000  ...                   
17                          TTL: Jakarta, 16 Mei 1966  ...                   
18                                        FUAD RIZAL,  ...                   
19  NIK: 3174010201780008 NPWP: 488337379015000 TT...  ...                  -
20                                 Ir. R AGUS HARYOTO  ...                  -
21          PURNOMO, UTAMA RASRINIK: 3578032408610001  ...                   
22                              NPWP: 097468813615000  ...                   
23                       TTL: SLEMAN, 24 Agustus 1961  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the following solution for the question:

```
def extract_names_and_shareholding_percentage_of_shareholders(self, df):
        shareholders_names = df.loc[(df['Jabatan'] == '-') & (df['Jumlah Lembar Saham'] != '-')]['Nama']

        pattern_shareholding_numbers = re.compile(r'[\d.]*\d+')

        shareholding_percentage_thousand_separator_removed = df[self.NUMBER_OF_SHARES].str.replace('.', '')
        shareholding_percentage_string = ' '.join(shareholding_percentage_thousand_separator_removed)
        matches = pattern_shareholding_numbers.findall(shareholding_percentage_string)
        float_matches = [float(shareholding) for shareholding in matches]
        shareholding_percentage_total = sum(float_matches)
        matches_percentages = [round(shareholding / shareholding_percentage_total * 100) for shareholding in float_matches]
        assert sum(matches_percentages) <= 100

        return(dict(zip(shareholders_names, matches_percentages)))

    def extract_names_and_shareholding_percentage_of_officers(self, df):
        officers_names = df.loc[(df['Jabatan'] != '-') & (df['Jumlah Lembar Saham'] == '-')]['Nama']

        pattern_shareholding_numbers = re.compile(r'[\d.]*\d+')

        shareholding_percentage_thousand_separator_removed = df[self.NUMBER_OF_SHARES].str.replace('.', '')
        shareholding_percentage_string = ' '.join(shareholding_percentage_thousand_separator_removed)
        matches = pattern_shareholding_numbers.findall(shareholding_percentage_string)
        float_matches = [float(shareholding) for shareholding in matches]
        shareholding_percentage_total = sum(float_matches)
        matches_percentages = [round(shareholding / shareholding_percentage_total * 100) for shareholding in float_matches]
        assert sum(matches_percentages) <= 100

        return(dict(zip(officers_names, matches_percentages)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude rows in column Total which value "-" using just.

```
df[df['Total'] != "-"]
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. So I can just do the following: 
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    if df[df["Total"] != '-']:
        shareholders = shareholder
        print(i, shareholders)
    else:
        officers = officer
        print(i, officers) ?

Comment: This is return whole of the data frame which column(Total) value is not "-" as your question, so, you don't need to inside of loop  @htm_01

Comment: But then it returns an error as follows: ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable